# Autofilter method of Range Class Failed trying to create sub sheets based on master data

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I understand this error has popped up many times before on this site, but I am using VBA for the first time.  I did what research from other posts I could, but, I just don't have the experience to gain much from them.

I was following the steps in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bOFNsdHiPk) YouTube video so that I could create separate sheets based on my master data.  I specifically need one sheet per different Contact, found in my 6th column.  There are more than 900 rows in the master, but there are 61 unique contacts, so I would expect 61 sub sheets to be generated.

[image: "Master"]

Note that I titled the above data, "Master," and my Sheet2, which lists all unique text entries (there were some accidentally-entered numerical entries that I needed to remove from the dataset), "Splitcode".

The following is the code I ran:

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()
'Step 1 - Name your ranges and Copy sheet
'Step 2 - Filter by Department and delete rows not applicable
'Step 3 - Loop until the end of the list
Dim Splitcode As Range
Sheets("List of Old Clients (A-Z)").Select
Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")
 
For Each cell In Splitcode
Sheets("List of Old Clients (A-Z)").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
 
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("Master")
.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="NOT EQUAL TO" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
 
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Next cell
End Sub
```

And here are screenshots showing the issue:

[image]

[image]

What can I try next?

Additional info:  I'd like to mention that, when I run the macro, a single sheet titled "A.Tudor" is created.  It appears to be a duplicate of the master data.

Comment: Maybe you have to change ´Criterial:="<>" & cell.Value´, or add and space after ´"NOT EQUAL TO "´

Comment: Is the code in the workbook containing these worksheets or in another workbook? Are both named ranges of workbook scope (use the Name Manager to find out)? Are you aware that `(6/19/65)` is not a valid sheet name?

Comment: @pepefiestas I tried your changes but without luck im afraid

Comment: @VBasic2008 There are dates errantly mixed in amongst the contact names (initials).  Is that an issue when running the macro?  As for your first question, I believe the code is in the same workbook as the sheets it's referring to . . . what do you suggest I do using the Name Manager?  Thanks!